# Adding multiple records with many-to-many (using extra fields) gives entity not found exception

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, many-to-many

I have got many to many mapping using extra fields. Here is my ReservationMM entity

```
  @Entity
@Table(name = "reservation_mm")
public class ReservationMM {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "warehouse_from_name")
    private String warehouseFromName;
    @Column(name = "warehouse_to_name")
    private String warehouseToName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reservationMM", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ReservationMMWarehousePosition> reservationMMWarehousePositions = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWarehouseFromName() {
        return warehouseFromName;
    }

    public void setWarehouseFromName(String warehouseFromName) {
        this.warehouseFromName = warehouseFromName;
    }

    public String getWarehouseToName() {
        return warehouseToName;
    }

    public void setWarehouseToName(String warehouseToName) {
        this.warehouseToName = warehouseToName;
    }

    public Set<ReservationMMWarehousePosition> getReservationMMWarehousePositions() {
        return reservationMMWarehousePositions;
    }

    public void setReservationMMWarehousePositions(Set<ReservationMMWarehousePosition> reservationMMWarehousePositions) {
        this.reservationMMWarehousePositions = reservationMMWarehousePositions;
    }
}
```

Here is my WarehousePosition entity

```
  @Entity
@Table(name = "warehouse_position")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class WarehousePosition implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "warehousePosition")
    private Set<ReservationMMWarehousePosition> reservationMMWarehousePositions = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<ReservationMMWarehousePosition> getReservationMMWarehousePositions() {
        return reservationMMWarehousePositions;
    }

    public void setReservationMMWarehousePositions(Set<ReservationMMWarehousePosition> reservationMMWarehousePositions) {
        this.reservationMMWarehousePositions = reservationMMWarehousePositions;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public WarehousePosition name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

And last table is ReservationMMWarehousePosition

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "reservation_mm_warehouse_position", catalog = "AMW_EMR")
public class ReservationMMWarehousePosition implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "reservation_mm_id")
    private ReservationMM reservationMM;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "warehouse_position_id")
    private WarehousePosition warehousePosition;
    @Column(name = "quantity_of_reservation")
    private Long quantityOfReservation;


    public ReservationMM getReservationMM() {
        return reservationMM;
    }

    public void setReservationMM(ReservationMM reservationMM) {
        this.reservationMM = reservationMM;
    }

    public WarehousePosition getWarehousePosition() {
        return warehousePosition;
    }

    public void setWarehousePosition(WarehousePosition warehousePosition) {
        this.warehousePosition = warehousePosition;
    }

    public Long getQuantityOfReservation() {
        return quantityOfReservation;
    }

    public void setQuantityOfReservation(Long quantityOfReservation) {
        this.quantityOfReservation = quantityOfReservation;
    }
}
```

Whe I'm trying to add multiple records ReservationMMWarehousePosition objects using next code, it gives me an exception

```
 @Override
public ReservationMM save(AddReservationMMDtoRequest addReservationMMDtoRequest) {
    ReservationMM reservationMM = new ReservationMM();
    reservationMM.setWarehouseFromName("sfd");
    reservationMM.setWarehouseToName("sdfsdf");
    reservationMM = reservationMMRepository.save(reservationMM);
    ReservationMMWarehousePosition reservationMMWarehousePosition = new ReservationMMWarehousePosition();
    reservationMMWarehousePosition.setQuantityOfReservation(34L);
    WarehousePosition warehousePosition1 = warehousePositionRepository.findOne(1l);
    reservationMMWarehousePosition.setWarehousePosition(warehousePosition1);
    WarehousePosition warehousePosition2 = warehousePositionRepository.findOne(2l);
    ReservationMMWarehousePosition reservationMMWarehousePosition1 = new ReservationMMWarehousePosition();
    reservationMMWarehousePosition1.setWarehousePosition(warehousePosition2);
    Set<ReservationMMWarehousePosition> reservationMMWarehousePositionSet = new HashSet<>();
    reservationMMWarehousePosition1.setQuantityOfReservation(43l);
    reservationMMWarehousePosition1.setReservationMM(reservationMM);
    reservationMMWarehousePosition.setReservationMM(reservationMM);
    reservationMMWarehousePositionSet.add(reservationMMWarehousePosition);
    reservationMMWarehousePositionSet.add(reservationMMWarehousePosition1);
    reservationMM.setReservationMMWarehousePositions(reservationMMWarehousePositionSet);
    ReservationMM save = reservationMMRepository.save(reservationMM);
    return save;
}
```

EXCEPTION:

> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find pl.amw.emr.domain.ReservationMMWarehousePosition with id pl.amw.emr.domain.ReservationMMWarehousePosition@40d102e8

I can't clearly understand, what I'm doing wrong? Or how to add multiple records?

UPDATE:
Full stacktrace

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find pl.amw.emr.domain.ReservationMMWarehousePosition with id pl.amw.emr.domain.ReservationMMWarehousePosition@40d102e8; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find pl.amw.emr.domain.ReservationMMWarehousePosition with id pl.amw.emr.domain.ReservationMMWarehousePosition@40d102e8
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:389)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy181.save(Unknown Source)
>       at pl.amw.emr.service.impl.ReservationMMServiceImpl.save(ReservationMMServiceImpl.java:54)
>       at pl.amw.emr.web.rest.PzoResource.getAllPzos(PzoResource.java:188)
>       at pl.amw.emr.web.rest.PzoResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$da28ff0c.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:48)
>       at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
>       at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
>       at pl.amw.emr.web.rest.PzoResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4f3c0dc1.getAllPzos()
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>       at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:111)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)

Comment: You never save your 2 ReservationMMWarehousePosition entities. Not sure this is the only problem. To get help, post the **complete** exception stack trace, as code.

Comment: @JBNizet, added full trace. check it pls :)

Comment: It's unreadable that way. Post it as code. Have you fixed the code and saved the ReservationMMWarehousePosition entities?

Comment: not yet. give me 3 mins pls

Comment: @JBNizet, but I can't understand how to save ReservationMMWarehousePosition entity using JPA repository cause it has got embedded primary key

Comment: The same way you save any other entity. That said, composite keys are a pain, and you don't seem to be comfortable with them. So why don't you just use an auto-generated ID, as for all your other entities?

Comment: @JBNizet cause I need to make many to many relation with extra key, I saw an example and did it, but I have got this troubles (

Comment: It's not a many to many association. It's two OneToMany/ManyToOne associations with an extra entity, named ReservationMMWarehousePosition. What makes you think that an entity having two ManyToOne associations can't have an auto-generated ID, like all other entities?